# Should you use "Using" for an asynchronous object?

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous

Is it safe to use a `Using` block for an asynchronous object? If the block is exited before async task is complete, will the object be disposed too soon? Will it be disposed properly when the task completes?

This code works, but I don't know whether it's abusing my memory.

```
For i = 1 To nPings
  Thread.Sleep(10)
  Using pPing As New System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
    AddHandler pPing.PingCompleted, AddressOf pingHandler
    pPing.SendAsync(ip, timeout)
  End Using
Next i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > If the block is exited before async task is complete, will the object be disposed too soon?

Yes. As soon as the `End Using` line completes, the `Ping` object will be disposed.

> > Will it be disposed properly when the task completes?

In your example, the `Ping` object will always be disposed of. However, this may or may not happen after the async code completes as that behavior, the way you've coded it, is undetermined.

To make this behavior more deterministic, dispose of the Ping object inside your `pingHandler` code, such that:

```
Class PingAsyncState

    Public Property Ping Ping
    Public Property int Timeout

End Class

For i = 1 To nPings
    Thread.Sleep(10)
    pPing As New System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
    AddHandler pPing.PingCompleted, AddressOf pingHandler
    pPing.SendAsync(ip, new PingAsyncState() With { .Ping = pPing, .Timeout = timeout })
Next i

Sub PingHandler(obj As Object)

    Dim state = CType(state, PingAsyncState)       

    ... code to do stuff ...

    state.Ping.Dispose()

End Sub
```

Also, if you inspect the code inside the `Ping.Dispose()`, you'll see that it closes various EventHandles. This may not cause an exception if the `Ping` object is disposed before the async completes, but it certainly puts the `Ping` object in an unstable state. You might find events not firing or the async complete handler code not being called or other subtle things happening.

Comment: Competent_tech is almost correct, in that the object will live to fire even after it is disposed. It's just that this does not happen 100% of the time. As Thilak Nathen said, the results are undetermined. 

Use the ping object after `End Using` worked until the Sub was exited, and then sometimes the last event would not fire. I ended up using a background worker and a synchronous ping.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure there are others that can give you detailed explanations of the underlying .Net framework behavior, but the upshot is that by attaching the event handler, the object will live to fire the event even after it is disposed.

You can prove this through the following modifications:

```
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    For i = 1 To 4
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
        Using pPing As New System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
            AddHandler pPing.PingCompleted, AddressOf pingHandler
            AddHandler pPing.Disposed, AddressOf pingDisposed
            pPing.SendAsync("someaddressthatmayormaynotwork.com", 10000)
        End Using
    Next i
    GC.Collect()
    Console.WriteLine("completed")


Public Sub pingHandler(sender As Object, e As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingCompletedEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("pingCompleted")
End Sub
Public Sub pingDisposed(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("Disposed")
End Sub
```

In this case, the dispose event can fire before the pingHandler event is fired if it takes too long to locate the URL or receive a response, yet the pingHandler event will always fire.

In general, it is a best practice to release async event handlers within the event so that you don't end up with scoping/closure scenarios like this one:

```
Public Sub pingHandler(sender As Object, e As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingCompletedEventArgs)
    If sender IsNot Nothing Then
        RemoveHandler DirectCast(sender, System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping).PingCompleted, AddressOf pingHandler
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("pingCompleted")
End Sub

Public Sub pingDisposed(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    If sender IsNot Nothing Then
        RemoveHandler DirectCast(sender, System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping).Disposed, AddressOf pingDisposed
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Disposed")
End Sub
```